# Typing jest test.each tagged template literal with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to type a jest `test.each` that uses a tagged template literal

```js
test.each`
  height | text
  ${10}  | ${undefined}
  ${20}  | ${undefined}
  ${10}  | ${'text'}
  ${20}  | ${'text'}
`('$height and $text work as expected', ({ height, text }) => {
  //...
});
```

- `height` is a number
- `text` is a string or undefined

I could, of course add my types to the tests' function parameters:

```
({ height, text }: { height: number, text: string? }) => {
  //...
});
```

But this is not what I want. `test.each` accepts a generic type

```js
test.each<MyType>`
  height | text
  // ...
`('$height and $text work as expected', ({ height, text }) => {
  //...
});
```

and I am wondering how I can use that type to infer the types in the function parameters.

Comment: `test.each<{ height: number, text: string? }>`?

Comment: Tried that already, that does not work

Comment: Could you expand on *"does not work"*? Give a [mre] of what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this question because I was looking for the same solution, but I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible because the types for the `each` function only use generics when the arguments passed are not of the template literal form. You can only use generic types when you pass in a [table](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeeachtablename-fn-timeout).

So your example would look like this:

```
test.each<{ height: number; text: string | undefined }>([
    { height: 10, text: undefined },
    { height: 20, text: undefined },
    { height: 10, text: 'text' },
    { height: 20, text: 'text' },
])('$height and $text work as expected', ({ height, text }) => {
    //...
});
```

Here is a link to the types file.  [@types/jest Each interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/caf92563269f8519826973a42a8f9e7aeaa1953f/types/jest/index.d.ts#L342)